# Bash script with a command with lots of single and double quotes

Tags: bash, curl, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes

I need to use the curl command:

curl -d '{ "auth_token": "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN", "text": "Hey, Look what I can do!" }' \http://localhost:3030/widgets/welcome

in a bash script but instead of **"Hey, Look what I can do!"** after the **"YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"**; I need a variable **$p** .

This is my first time trying a bash script and read the tutorials on quotes and such but I still am not able to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to read the data from a here document (a type of dynamically created temporary file), rather then trying to quote the entire thing as a string:

```
curl -d@- http://localhost:3030/widgets/welcome <<EOF
{ "auth_token": "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN",
  "text": "$p" }
EOF
```

If the argument to `-d` begins with a `@`, the remainder of the argument is taken as the name of a file containing the data. A file name of `-` indicates standard input, and the standard input to `curl` is supplied by the lines between the `EOF` tokens.

The alternative is to double-quote the string and escape all the embedded double quotes. Yuck.

```
... -d "{\"auth_token\": \"YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN\", \"text\": \"$p\"}" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to chepner's very good answer:

```
data=$( printf '{"auth_token":"YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN","text":"%s"}' "$p" )
curl -d "$data" http://localhost:3030/widgets/welcome
```